# Ansible postgresql_query: how can I insert list variable as json type?

Tags: ansible, jinja2, ansible-2.x, ansible-template

I have a table with the column name `contacts` (format Json) and the contacts API call returns the object in list format as below.

`contacts: ["test@gmail.com", "test2@gmail.com" ]`

PSQl query code I am trying:

```yaml
- name: Insert to db
  postgresql_query:
    db: xxx
    login_user: xxx
    login_password: xxx
    query: INSERT INTO test_table (id, contacts) VALUES (%s, %s)

    positional_args:
    - 1
    - '{{ contacts }}'
```

Error:

```
Invalid input syntax for type json\n LINE 1:... Token \"'\" is invalid
```

I believe it's some quotes issue but I couldn't figure out exactly how to pass list value to JSON type.

Comment: It is unclear from your question if `contacts` contains a string representation of a json value or if it directly contains a list. Please make this [mcve](/help/mcve). The documentation has quite a few [examples](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/community/postgresql/postgresql_query_module.html#examples) of passing lists as arguments.

Comment: It is in list format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using ascii filter along with json worked for me.

```
 '{{ contacts|to_json(ensure_ascii=False) }}'
```

Answer (score 2):

Convert *contacts* to JSON

```yaml
    positional_args:
      - 1
      - '{{ contacts|to_json }}'
```